How to implement search functionality over a plain text returned from an API in vue js3 (Vuetify)?
I have a plain text (data is just dumped from a log file) returned from an API say

The data from API is maintained in a pinia store
I'm trying to implement search functionality over this entire log of data.
Here's the code
  <template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="3">
        <v-text-field  v-model="searchText" @keyup="searchLogs">
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-card >
      <div>
        <p style="white-space: pre">{{ TestResults }}</p>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

import { useDataStore } from '@/stores/dataStore'
const {TestResults } = storeToRefs(useDataStore ())

const searchText = ref('Search')


const searchLogs = () => {
  let logRefData;
  
}

TestResults  has the response.
I'm able to get the data in rows in UI since I have used "white-space: pre". How do I filter the search text inside this entire text which is a string? (Like filter js function is used on arrays)
Also, my script code is in typescript.
If the search text is present in a particular row, the entire row should be displayed.
Eg:
Search text :
xx
Search result:

Search text :
2/7/23
Search result:


What is your data's shape? You cannot use .filter on it? What's the issue exactly with the filtering?

I have edited the data. Data is just a plain text. If filters can't be used, how can the data be filtered since its a plain text (String). But displayed in rows

I mean, if it's just a single string of text then go back to the API and look with them what might be the issue. You could try to organize it into an array (or something else) yourself by using regexes but this is very prone to errors. So having a filter system on a plain string is not really feasible. Very weird that the API is just throwing text and not something more friendly tho.

I am also very curious as to how you managed to organize the different values given a specific name, place, and date. Could we please have a sample of the given API response?
